# Converter funções PHP em JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Preciso converter algumas funções em PHP para JS, por que vou precisar colocar todas essas funções dentro de um arquivo .js.

Atualmente tenho o seguinte em PHP:

```
$basicoUS_mensal=processaValor("url_aqui");

function processaValor($url) {
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $aspas = strpos($result, "'");
    $valor = substr($result, $aspas+1, -3);
    return $valor;
}
```

A URL retorna da seguinte forma, por isso tem a função que pega somente o valor: **document.write('11,90');**

Na página PHP eu estava utilizando o seguinte script, segue parte dele:

```
var plano_basicoUS = {
    1: parseFloat(<? echo str_replace(',', '.', $basicoUS_mensal); ?>),
 };
```

Como no .js não funciona o PHP, preciso alterar essa parte para que funcione no arquivo .js.

No caso acima o valor de var `plano_basicoUS[1]` seria: 11.90

Qual alternativa eu poderia usar?

Answer (score 1):

Basta alterar a função `processaValor`:

```
$basicoUS_mensal=processaValor("url_aqui");

function processaValor($url) {
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $aspas = strpos($result, "'");
    $valor = substr($result, $aspas+1, -3);
    return $str_replace(',', '.', $valor);
}
```

Essa alteração fará com que a função `processaValor` retorne 11.90 para o JS.

Comment: Olha eu ai de novo heim João! rsrs Mas e como ficaria no JS? Pois la não funciona o `<? php ?>`

Comment: O problema é como pegar esse valor no JS, da forma que estou utilizando só funciona se estiver em uma página PHP, porém eu preciso que fique dentro de um arquivo .js.

Comment: Entendo... Teria que fazer uma gambiarra aí, haha... Passar o script pra dentro do echo, mais ou menos assim: https://ideone.com/r6FR7X. Olhando no Stack gringo, caso você entenda inglês, tem o recomendável. Fazer isso em uma API e acessar esses dados utilizando uma requisição: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: Já tinha visto essa outra pergunta, mas naõ consegui implementar rs. Não entendi sua gambiarra, veja bem: tenho o arquivo index.php onde esta o conteúdo HTML, tenho o arquivo valor.js onde esta o script acima, e tem o arquivo valor.php onde estao os valores com a função em PHP. O problema é só no arquivo valor.js, na parte: `var plano_basicoUS = {`, onde preciso pegar o valor da URL como se fosse no PHP. Se tivesse como fazer tudo no JS, colocar direto a URL ali, seria até melhor, ai não usaria o arquivo valor.php.

Comment: Realmente não tem como acessar esses dados no arquivo .js. Uma saída é você alterar a extensão do arquivo .HTML para .PHP e então fazer o que eu fiz aí lá - assim você consegue puxar os dados direto do outro arquivo PHP. Do jeito que está, não tem como você usar PHP em um arquivo .JS, hehe

Comment: Outra saída, e a mais correta na minha opinião, é criar uma mini API no arquivo PHP que você tem. Ao acessar `valor.php`, ele te retornaria um JSON com os valores de cada categoria, mais ou menos assim: https://ideone.com/h4RecK e aí fica simples consumir esses dados usando uma requisição AJAX.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78809/discussion-between-wendler-and-joao-pedro-henrique).